# Make the point in the middle of each grid in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the data.

```
df <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = LETTERS[6:10], z = rnorm(5))
```

Below are the codes to generate a point plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z, size = z)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, stroke = 1, colour = 'black')
```

[image]

I'm wondering how to make each point into the middle of each grid. Something like this.
[image]

Comment: OK. I found it worked by just using the geom_tile() function.

Comment: As you have found a solution to your question you might post (and accept) it as an answer to help others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I found it worked by adding a geom_tile function.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile(fill = NA, colour = 'black') +
  geom_point(aes(fill = z, size = z), shape = 21, stroke = 1, colour = 'black') +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, colour = 'black'),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, colour = 'black'),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_blank())
```